# Why aren't my fonts getting registered?

Tags: fonts, itext

I have a program using iTextSharp that includes the code

```
FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();

foreach (string fontname in FontFactory.RegisteredFonts)
{
   Log.Info("**** Found registered font: " + fontname);
}
```

When I run it (using Mono on a CentOS box), the log shows only the core PostScript fonts:

- zapfdingbats
- times-roman
- times-italic
- helvetica-boldoblique
- courier-boldoblique
- helvetica-bold
- helvetica
- courier-oblique
- helvetica-oblique
- courier-bold
- times-bolditalic
- courier
- times-bold
- symbol

But I have 156 TTF files under my `/usr/share/fonts` directory tree (which is one of the directories mentioned in the code for the `RegisterDirectories` function).  Why aren't these being registered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are subtle differences between iText and iTextSharp.

In iText, `registerDirectories()` looks like this:

```
public int registerDirectories() {
    int count = 0;
    String windir = System.getenv("windir");
    String fileseparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    if (windir != null && fileseparator != null) {
        count += registerDirectory(windir + fileseparator + "fonts");
    }
    count += registerDirectory("/usr/share/X11/fonts", true);
    count += registerDirectory("/usr/X/lib/X11/fonts", true);
    count += registerDirectory("/usr/openwin/lib/X11/fonts", true);
    count += registerDirectory("/usr/share/fonts", true);
    count += registerDirectory("/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts", true);
    count += registerDirectory("/Library/Fonts");
    count += registerDirectory("/System/Library/Fonts");
    return count;
}
```

In iTextSharp however, the method looks like this:

```
public virtual int RegisterDirectories() {
    string dir = Path.Combine(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)), "Fonts");
    return RegisterDirectory(dir);
}
```

Java is platform independent, so we have to look for the 'usual suspects'. C# is Windows specific, so we can depend on the environment to tell us where to find fonts. Your question tells us that Mono doesn't support this, so you'll have to use `FontFactory.RegisterDirectory("/usr/share/fonts");`