# creating PDF/A-1b without needing a Helvetica Font file

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext, pdfa

I need to create some simple but PDF/A-1b conform PDF-Files using iText.

My first approach looks like this:

```
Document document = new Document(Pagesize.A4); 
ByteArrayOutputStream pdfBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream); 

PdfAWriter pdfAWriter 
  = PdfAWriter.geInstance (document, pdfBuffer, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDFA_1B);
pdfAWriter.createXmpMetadata();

Font fixedFont = FontFactory.getFont("Courier New", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 10, Font.NORMAL); 

document.open();

Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Hello World", fixedFont);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(chunk); 
document.add(paragraph);  

document.close();

// this is pseudo code to transfer the Buffer to a real file
writeByteArrayToFile(pdfBuffer.toByteArray());
```

Thos Code generates an Error Message:

> All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: Helvetica

Looking around I found out that Helvetica is the default Document Font of iTextn which cannot be changed, that this is a Base PDF Font which is not embedded by default and that I can only embed it if I have a Helvetica pfb or ttf File (which I do not have and do not want to buy since I am not planning to use that font at all in my documents).

There is no need for any Helvetica Text in my PDF at all. I need to generate PDF/A-1b which requires to embed all fonts including the PDF Base Fonts.

So is this a Bug? What is the correct Way to generate a PDF/A with iText if there is no Helvetica Font file available?

Comment: That is the normal behavior. If you cannot add the font to the pdf just replace that font.

Comment: I suspect that you have not registered the fonts and what FontFactory is returning is the default font that happens to be Helvetica.

Comment: Could you take a look at the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/52736441/3169868

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction would be in line with the comment made by @rekire: This is a very strange question. One of the imperative requirements of a PDF/A file is that you embed every font. Now you are asking for a PDF/A document without embedding a font such as Helvetica. That would be a document without any text.

You did not respond to this reaction, but a possible reply could be: if you look at my code, you clearly see that I am not using Helvetica, I am using `"Courier New"`. Why do I need Helvetica if I use Courier New?

That's my second reaction: **You are not using Courier New!** This line is not sufficient:

```
Font fixedFont = FontFactory.getFont("Courier New", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 10, Font.NORMAL);
```

I don't see you registering `courier.ttf` anywhere. Hence iText does not know where to find Courier New. It uses Helvetica instead. When I consult [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) (a book I can highly recommend), I find the following questions:

- [Why doesn't FontFactory.GetFont("Known Font Name", floatSize) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007492/why-doesnt-fontfactory-getfontknown-font-name-floatsize-work)
- [How to use Verdana Font in Stamper (iText PDF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404418/how-to-use-verdana-font-in-stamper-itext-pdf)
- [Why aren't my fonts getting registered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635212/why-arent-my-fonts-getting-registered)

The answers to these questions explain what is going wrong in your example. Note that you'll find some complete PDF/A examples in the [sandbox](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/pdfa) on the official iText site.

Comment: Can an example code snippet be provided for resolving this issue?